# Hampel Matlab vs R

Tags: r, matlab, outliers

I am trying to rewrite code from Matlab in R and I am failing at the Hampel-Filter which seems to be distinct.

```
absmeasuredAccelerations<-(9.817899,9.923724,9.915009,9.414430,9.912013,9.822199,9.662423,9.809928,9.812976,9.883809)
```

1. The vector I am applying the Hampel-Filter in Matlab and R is identical as seen below.

[image]

Matlab Source:

```
Filtered = hampel(absmeasuredAccelerations,30,0.05);
```

In R:

```
Filtered<- hampel(absmeasuredAccelerations, k=15,t0=0.05)$y
```

Comparing the output between Matlab and R, there is a significant distinction as seen below:

[image]

Assuming the implementation of both filters is distinct, however, somehow it must be possible to reproduce results? Anyone has some ideas or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: In the matlab code, try using an odd number, 31. The R argument `k` gives a window length 2*k+1 in indices, always odd.

Comment: Thank you for the hint Rui. Changing the window length does not help.

Comment: Assuming you are talking about the _pracma_ package. From the documentation:
`At the lower and upper end the time series values are preserved.`

This is due to the fact that for values 1..k. there aren't k previous elements available for the sliding window. You'd have to figure out what Matlab does there.

Comment: Thank you for your reply supik. 
The figures represent calculated vector lengths of 3-dimensional acceleration data recorded from a Nexus 6P smartphones, assuming 300-400 Hz measurements. A given window-length of e.g. 30 would leave the lower and upper ends of the time-series untouched using the pracma package. 30 values represent, depending on the measurement frequency, 100-130 ms. As such, it think it would be fair to assume that this can be neglected.
However, it would be interesting to know how Matlab handles this issue.

Comment: window-length adjusted to 30 does still show dicrepancies